# Capybara choose first occurrence of label

Tags: capybara

I have the following radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" value="0" /> Correct
<input type="radio" value="1" /> Wrong
<input type="radio" value="2" /> Wrong
<input type="radio" value="3" /> Wrong
```

I'm trying to use Capybara to select the first input with label "Wrong".  From the documentation, it seems like this should work:

```
choose first "Wrong"
```

But I get an error message:

```
Ambiguous match, found 4 elements matching radio button nil
```

Help?

Comment: Are you sure that your html sample is correct? To my knowledge, input elements are not allowed to have inner text.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  My actual HTML doesn't look like that.  I fixed it.

Comment: Please update your sample then.

Answer (score 2):

The `first` needs to be the value of the `match` option. The `match` option defines the matching algorithm (see the [readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#strategy) for all available options).

The statement should look like:

```
choose "Wrong", :match => :first
```

Comment: I get a different error when I do that: `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using?